# Is there any plane in a quintic threefold?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Sorry to bother if this question is trivial: For a general smooth quintic threefold $V$ in $\mathbb{P}^4$ over an algebraic closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Is there a plane in $V$?

If Yes, how do I find it(them)? If no, under what condition there is a plane?

Thanks for any hints and comments.

Comment: Any smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n, n\geq 4$, the Picard group is $\mathbb{Z}$, genertaed by the hyperplane section. So, there can not be any plane in $V$ as in your case (no generality assumption is necessary).

Comment: Thanks @Mohan, just want to make sure, is that because of the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem?

Comment: Yes, or Grothendieck-Lefshetz for arbitrary characteristic.

Comment: Also, if you know of the $2875$ lines on a general quintic threefold, there'd be lines without bound if a plane was in there. Not a proof, just a mnemonic.

Comment: Thanks @Jan-MagnusØkland, it's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an elementary argument (I first saw it in http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~jstarr/papers/appendix3.pdf):

Let $X=V(F)$ and suppose $X$ contains $P=\{X_0=X_1=0\}\subset\mathbb{P}^4$. Then, we can write
$$F=F_0X_0+F_1X_1,$$
as $F\in \langle X_0,X_1\rangle$ by definition. Now, 
\begin{align*}
\partial_0 F|_P &= F_0\\
\partial_1 F|_P &= F_1\\
\partial_2 F|_P &= 0\\
\partial_3 F|_P &= 0.
\end{align*}
Now, we notice that $F_0,F_1$ have a common zero when restricted to $P$, so $X=V(F)$ is not smooth.

In general, this shows we cannot have any planes in a hypersurface exceeding half the dimension of the hypersurface.